# simple-scan snap package does not work, symbolic link errors, Samsung Xpress M2070W

Tags: scanner, samsung, simplescan

Simple scan is not working for me. I get a bunch of error messages when I run `simple-scan` in terminal:

```
philip@Aspire-A715-71G:~$ simple-scan
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/home/philip/snap/simple-scan/34/.local/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gtk.Settings.FileChooser.gschema.xml': File exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/home/philip/snap/simple-scan/34/.local/share/glib-2.0/schemas/10_gsettings-desktop-schemas.gschema.override': File exists
Cannot load module /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/3.0.0/immodules/im-ibus.so: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/3.0.0/immodules/im-ibus.so: undefined symbol: ibus_bus_get_service_name
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/3.0.0/immodules/im-ibus.so does not export GTK+ IM module API: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/3.0.0/immodules/im-ibus.so: undefined symbol: ibus_bus_get_service_name
cp: '/home/philip/.config/user-dirs.locale' and '/home/philip/.config/user-dirs.locale' are the same file
```

I have a combined printer/scanner: Samsung Xpress M2070W.

The printer works fine, no problem with that.

I have installed `hplip` and `uld` (from Samsung).

Can I get help troubleshooting?

I run Ubuntu 18.04.

```
philip@Aspire-A715-71G:~$ sane-find-scanner

  # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

  # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0003 at 002:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x04f2/0xb5f7 at 001:005: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x04ca/0x3016 at 001:003: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
found USB scanner (vendor=0x04e8 [Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd.], product=0x3469 [M2070 Series]) at libusb:001:009
could not open USB device 0x045e/0x0780 at 001:006: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x0846/0x9052 at 001:007: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x2109/0x2813 at 001:004: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x2109/0x2813 at 001:002: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x04f3/0x0c03 at 001:008: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0002 at 001:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
  # Your USB scanner was (probably) detected. It may or may not be supported by
  # SANE. Try scanimage -L and read the backend's manpage.

  # Not checking for parallel port scanners.

  # Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
  # can't be detected by this program.

  # You may want to run this program as root to find all devices. Once you
  # found the scanner devices, be sure to adjust access permissions as
  # necessary.
```

---

```
philip@Aspire-A715-71G:~$ sudo simple-scan
[sudo] password for philip: 
/snap/simple-scan/34/bin/desktop-launch: line 23: /root/.config/user-dirs.dirs: No such file or directory
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/home/philip/../home/philip/Documents': No such file or directory
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/home/philip/../home/philip/Desktop': No such file or directory
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/home/philip/../home/philip/Downloads': No such file or directory
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/home/philip/../home/philip/Music': No such file or directory
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/home/philip/../home/philip/Pictures': No such file or directory
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/home/philip/../home/philip/Videos': No such file or directory
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/home/philip/../home/philip/Templates': No such file or directory
Cannot load module /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/3.0.0/immodules/im-ibus.so: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/3.0.0/immodules/im-ibus.so: undefined symbol: ibus_bus_get_service_name
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/3.0.0/immodules/im-ibus.so does not export GTK+ IM module API: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gtk-3.0/3.0.0/immodules/im-ibus.so: undefined symbol: ibus_bus_get_service_name
/snap/simple-scan/34/bin/desktop-launch: line 23: /root/.config/user-dirs.dirs: No such file or directory
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/home/philip/../home/philip/Documents': No such file or directory
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/home/philip/../home/philip/Desktop': No such file or directory
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/home/philip/../home/philip/Downloads': No such file or directory
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/home/philip/../home/philip/Music': No such file or directory
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/home/philip/../home/philip/Pictures': No such file or directory
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/home/philip/../home/philip/Videos': No such file or directory
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/home/philip/../home/philip/Templates': No such file or directory
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/root/snap/simple-scan/34/.local/share/glib-2.0/schemas/com.canonical.unity-gtk-module.gschema.xml': File exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/root/snap/simple-scan/34/.local/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.SimpleScan.gschema.xml': File exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/root/snap/simple-scan/34/.local/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.desktop.a11y.applications.gschema.xml': File exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/root/snap/simple-scan/34/.local/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.desktop.a11y.gschema.xml': File exists
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/root/snap/simple-scan/34/.local/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org.gnome.desktop.a11y.keyboard.gschema.xml': File exists
```

---

```
philip@Aspire-A715-71G:~$ which simple-scan
/snap/bin/simple-scan
philip@Aspire-A715-71G:~$ snap list | grep simple
simple-scan           3.28.1                     34    stable    canonical*   classic
philip@Aspire-A715-71G:~$ apt-cache policy simple-scan
simple-scan:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 3.28.0-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
     3.28.0-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

---

```
philip@Aspire-A715-71G:~$ sudo dpkg-query -L simple-scan
[sudo] password for philip: 
dpkg-query: package 'simple-scan' is not installed
Use dpkg --info (= dpkg-deb --info) to examine archive files,
and dpkg --contents (= dpkg-deb --contents) to list their contents.
```

Ok, I saw that one package was not installed in Ubuntu Software, so I installed that also.

[image: screenshot]

No, luck...

[image: screenshot]

Now I get this in terminal:

```
philip@Aspire-A715-71G:~$ which simple-scan
/usr/bin/simple-scan
philip@Aspire-A715-71G:~$ snap list | grep simple
simple-scan           3.28.1                     34    stable    canonical*   classic
philip@Aspire-A715-71G:~$ apt-cache policy simple-scan
simple-scan:
  Installed: 3.28.0-0ubuntu1
  Candidate: 3.28.0-0ubuntu1
  Version table:
 *** 3.28.0-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

So, now simple-scan is installed...

Now I only have to get the scanner working. :)

```
philip@Aspire-A715-71G:~$ sudo snap remove simple-scan
[sudo] password for philip: 
simple-scan removed
```

How can simple-scan still be installed after doing that command?

What is snap anyway?

I still get this in Terminal:

```
sane-find-scanner

  # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

  # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0003 at 002:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x04f2/0xb5f7 at 001:005: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x04ca/0x3016 at 001:003: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x045e/0x0780 at 001:006: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x0846/0x9052 at 001:007: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x2109/0x2813 at 001:004: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x2109/0x2813 at 001:002: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x04e8/0x3469 at 001:010: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x04f3/0x0c03 at 001:008: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0002 at 001:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
  # No USB scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel driver for your USB host controller and have setup
  # the USB system correctly. See man sane-usb for details.

  # Not checking for parallel port scanners.

  # Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
  # can't be detected by this program.

  # You may want to run this program as root to find all devices. Once you
  # found the scanner devices, be sure to adjust access permissions as
  # necessary.
```

Ok, so now I have done this according to the thread "Samsung M2070W scanner no longer working in 17.10"

```
philip@Aspire-A715-71G:~/Downloads$ cd uld
philip@Aspire-A715-71G:~/Downloads/uld$ ls
i386  install-printer.sh  install-scanner.sh  install.sh  noarch  uninstall-printer.sh  uninstall-scanner.sh  uninstall.sh  x86_64
philip@Aspire-A715-71G:~/Downloads/uld$ sudo ./install.sh
[sudo] password for philip: 
**** Running install ...
**** Press 'Enter' to continue or 'q' and then 'Enter' to quit. : 
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
END-USER LICENSE AGREEMENT...

**** Do you agree ? [y/n] : y
**** Are you going to use network devices ? If yes, it is recommended to configure your firewall.
**** If you want to configure firewall automatically, enter 'y' or just press 'Enter'. To skip, enter 'n'. : n
**** Registering CUPS backend ...
**** CUPS restart OK.
**** Print driver has been installed successfully.
**** Registering SANE backend ...
**** Restarting udev ...
**** Scan driver has been installed successfully.
**** Install finished.
philip@Aspire-A715-71G:~/Downloads/uld$ sane-find-scanner

  # sane-find-scanner will now attempt to detect your scanner. If the
  # result is different from what you expected, first make sure your
  # scanner is powered up and properly connected to your computer.

  # No SCSI scanners found. If you expected something different, make sure that
  # you have loaded a kernel SCSI driver for your SCSI adapter.

could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0003 at 002:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x04f2/0xb5f7 at 001:006: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x04ca/0x3016 at 001:004: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x045e/0x0780 at 001:007: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x24a9/0x1302 at 001:010: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x0846/0x9052 at 001:008: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x2109/0x2813 at 001:005: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x2109/0x2813 at 001:003: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
found USB scanner (vendor=0x04e8 [Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd.], product=0x3469 [M2070 Series]) at libusb:001:002
could not open USB device 0x04f3/0x0c03 at 001:009: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
could not open USB device 0x1d6b/0x0002 at 001:001: Access denied (insufficient permissions)
  # Your USB scanner was (probably) detected. It may or may not be supported by
  # SANE. Try scanimage -L and read the backend's manpage.

  # Not checking for parallel port scanners.

  # Most Scanners connected to the parallel port or other proprietary ports
  # can't be detected by this program.

  # You may want to run this program as root to find all devices. Once you
  # found the scanner devices, be sure to adjust access permissions as
  # necessary.
philip@Aspire-A715-71G:~/Downloads/uld$ cd /opt/smfp-common/scanner/lib/
philip@Aspire-A715-71G:/opt/smfp-common/scanner/lib$ ls
libsane-smfp.so.1.0.1
philip@Aspire-A715-71G:/opt/smfp-common/scanner/lib$ cd /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane
philip@Aspire-A715-71G:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane$ ls
libsane-abaton.so.1               libsane-coolscan.so.1            libsane-hp3500.so.1          libsane-kvs40xx.so.1           libsane-p5.so.1               libsane-snapscan.so.1
libsane-abaton.so.1.0.27          libsane-coolscan.so.1.0.27       libsane-hp3500.so.1.0.27     libsane-kvs40xx.so.1.0.27      libsane-p5.so.1.0.27          libsane-snapscan.so.1.0.27
libsane-agfafocus.so.1            libsane-dc210.so.1               libsane-hp3900.so.1          libsane-leo.so.1               libsane-pie.so.1              libsane-sp15c.so.1
libsane-agfafocus.so.1.0.27       libsane-dc210.so.1.0.27          libsane-hp3900.so.1.0.27     libsane-leo.so.1.0.27          libsane-pie.so.1.0.27         libsane-sp15c.so.1.0.27
libsane-apple.so.1                libsane-dc240.so.1               libsane-hp4200.so.1          libsane-lexmark.so.1           libsane-pieusb.so.1           libsane-st400.so.1
libsane-apple.so.1.0.27           libsane-dc240.so.1.0.27          libsane-hp4200.so.1.0.27     libsane-lexmark.so.1.0.27      libsane-pieusb.so.1.0.27      libsane-st400.so.1.0.27
libsane-artec_eplus48u.so.1       libsane-dc25.so.1                libsane-hp5400.so.1          libsane-ma1509.so.1            libsane-pixma.so.1            libsane-stv680.so.1
libsane-artec_eplus48u.so.1.0.27  libsane-dc25.so.1.0.27           libsane-hp5400.so.1.0.27     libsane-ma1509.so.1.0.27       libsane-pixma.so.1.0.27       libsane-stv680.so.1.0.27
libsane-artec.so.1                libsane-dell1600n_net.so.1       libsane-hp5590.so.1          libsane-magicolor.so.1         libsane-plustek_pp.so.1       libsane-tamarack.so.1
libsane-artec.so.1.0.27           libsane-dell1600n_net.so.1.0.27  libsane-hp5590.so.1.0.27     libsane-magicolor.so.1.0.27    libsane-plustek_pp.so.1.0.27  libsane-tamarack.so.1.0.27
libsane-as6e.so.1                 libsane-dll.so.1                 libsane-hpaio.so.1           libsane-matsushita.so.1        libsane-plustek.so.1          libsane-teco1.so.1
libsane-as6e.so.1.0.27            libsane-dll.so.1.0.27            libsane-hpaio.so.1.0.0       libsane-matsushita.so.1.0.27   libsane-plustek.so.1.0.27     libsane-teco1.so.1.0.27
libsane-avision.so.1              libsane-dmc.so.1                 libsane-hpljm1005.so.1       libsane-microtek2.so.1         libsane-pnm.so.1              libsane-teco2.so.1
libsane-avision.so.1.0.27         libsane-dmc.so.1.0.27            libsane-hpljm1005.so.1.0.27  libsane-microtek2.so.1.0.27    libsane-pnm.so.1.0.27         libsane-teco2.so.1.0.27
libsane-bh.so.1                   libsane-epjitsu.so.1             libsane-hpsj5s.so.1          libsane-microtek.so.1          libsane-qcam.so.1             libsane-teco3.so.1
libsane-bh.so.1.0.27              libsane-epjitsu.so.1.0.27        libsane-hpsj5s.so.1.0.27     libsane-microtek.so.1.0.27     libsane-qcam.so.1.0.27        libsane-teco3.so.1.0.27
libsane-canon630u.so.1            libsane-epson2.so.1              libsane-hp.so.1              libsane-mustek_pp.so.1         libsane-ricoh.so.1            libsane-test.so.1
libsane-canon630u.so.1.0.27       libsane-epson2.so.1.0.27         libsane-hp.so.1.0.27         libsane-mustek_pp.so.1.0.27    libsane-ricoh.so.1.0.27       libsane-test.so.1.0.27
libsane-canon_dr.so.1             libsane-epsonds.so.1             libsane-hs2p.so.1            libsane-mustek.so.1            libsane-rts8891.so.1          libsane-u12.so.1
libsane-canon_dr.so.1.0.27        libsane-epsonds.so.1.0.27        libsane-hs2p.so.1.0.27       libsane-mustek.so.1.0.27       libsane-rts8891.so.1.0.27     libsane-u12.so.1.0.27
libsane-canon_pp.so.1             libsane-epson.so.1               libsane-ibm.so.1             libsane-mustek_usb2.so.1       libsane-s9036.so.1            libsane-umax1220u.so.1
libsane-canon_pp.so.1.0.27        libsane-epson.so.1.0.27          libsane-ibm.so.1.0.27        libsane-mustek_usb2.so.1.0.27  libsane-s9036.so.1.0.27       libsane-umax1220u.so.1.0.27
libsane-canon.so.1                libsane-fujitsu.so.1             libsane-kodakaio.so.1        libsane-mustek_usb.so.1        libsane-sceptre.so.1          libsane-umax_pp.so.1
libsane-canon.so.1.0.27           libsane-fujitsu.so.1.0.27        libsane-kodakaio.so.1.0.27   libsane-mustek_usb.so.1.0.27   libsane-sceptre.so.1.0.27     libsane-umax_pp.so.1.0.27
libsane-cardscan.so.1             libsane-genesys.so.1             libsane-kodak.so.1           libsane-nec.so.1               libsane-sharp.so.1            libsane-umax.so.1
libsane-cardscan.so.1.0.27        libsane-genesys.so.1.0.27        libsane-kodak.so.1.0.27      libsane-nec.so.1.0.27          libsane-sharp.so.1.0.27       libsane-umax.so.1.0.27
libsane-coolscan2.so.1            libsane-gphoto2.so.1             libsane-kvs1025.so.1         libsane-net.so.1               libsane-sm3600.so.1           libsane-xerox_mfp.so.1
libsane-coolscan2.so.1.0.27       libsane-gphoto2.so.1.0.27        libsane-kvs1025.so.1.0.27    libsane-net.so.1.0.27          libsane-sm3600.so.1.0.27      libsane-xerox_mfp.so.1.0.27
libsane-coolscan3.so.1            libsane-gt68xx.so.1              libsane-kvs20xx.so.1         libsane-niash.so.1             libsane-sm3840.so.1
libsane-coolscan3.so.1.0.27       libsane-gt68xx.so.1.0.27         libsane-kvs20xx.so.1.0.27    libsane-niash.so.1.0.27        libsane-sm3840.so.1.0.27
philip@Aspire-A715-71G:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane$ sudo ln -s /opt/smfp-common/scanner/lib/libsane-smfp.so.1.0.1 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane/libsane-smfp.so.1
philip@Aspire-A715-71G:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane$ ls
libsane-abaton.so.1               libsane-coolscan.so.1            libsane-hp3500.so.1          libsane-kvs40xx.so.1           libsane-p5.so.1               libsane-smfp.so.1
libsane-abaton.so.1.0.27          libsane-coolscan.so.1.0.27       libsane-hp3500.so.1.0.27     libsane-kvs40xx.so.1.0.27      libsane-p5.so.1.0.27          libsane-snapscan.so.1
libsane-agfafocus.so.1            libsane-dc210.so.1               libsane-hp3900.so.1          libsane-leo.so.1               libsane-pie.so.1              libsane-snapscan.so.1.0.27
libsane-agfafocus.so.1.0.27       libsane-dc210.so.1.0.27          libsane-hp3900.so.1.0.27     libsane-leo.so.1.0.27          libsane-pie.so.1.0.27         libsane-sp15c.so.1
libsane-apple.so.1                libsane-dc240.so.1               libsane-hp4200.so.1          libsane-lexmark.so.1           libsane-pieusb.so.1           libsane-sp15c.so.1.0.27
libsane-apple.so.1.0.27           libsane-dc240.so.1.0.27          libsane-hp4200.so.1.0.27     libsane-lexmark.so.1.0.27      libsane-pieusb.so.1.0.27      libsane-st400.so.1
libsane-artec_eplus48u.so.1       libsane-dc25.so.1                libsane-hp5400.so.1          libsane-ma1509.so.1            libsane-pixma.so.1            libsane-st400.so.1.0.27
libsane-artec_eplus48u.so.1.0.27  libsane-dc25.so.1.0.27           libsane-hp5400.so.1.0.27     libsane-ma1509.so.1.0.27       libsane-pixma.so.1.0.27       libsane-stv680.so.1
libsane-artec.so.1                libsane-dell1600n_net.so.1       libsane-hp5590.so.1          libsane-magicolor.so.1         libsane-plustek_pp.so.1       libsane-stv680.so.1.0.27
libsane-artec.so.1.0.27           libsane-dell1600n_net.so.1.0.27  libsane-hp5590.so.1.0.27     libsane-magicolor.so.1.0.27    libsane-plustek_pp.so.1.0.27  libsane-tamarack.so.1
libsane-as6e.so.1                 libsane-dll.so.1                 libsane-hpaio.so.1           libsane-matsushita.so.1        libsane-plustek.so.1          libsane-tamarack.so.1.0.27
libsane-as6e.so.1.0.27            libsane-dll.so.1.0.27            libsane-hpaio.so.1.0.0       libsane-matsushita.so.1.0.27   libsane-plustek.so.1.0.27     libsane-teco1.so.1
libsane-avision.so.1              libsane-dmc.so.1                 libsane-hpljm1005.so.1       libsane-microtek2.so.1         libsane-pnm.so.1              libsane-teco1.so.1.0.27
libsane-avision.so.1.0.27         libsane-dmc.so.1.0.27            libsane-hpljm1005.so.1.0.27  libsane-microtek2.so.1.0.27    libsane-pnm.so.1.0.27         libsane-teco2.so.1
libsane-bh.so.1                   libsane-epjitsu.so.1             libsane-hpsj5s.so.1          libsane-microtek.so.1          libsane-qcam.so.1             libsane-teco2.so.1.0.27
libsane-bh.so.1.0.27              libsane-epjitsu.so.1.0.27        libsane-hpsj5s.so.1.0.27     libsane-microtek.so.1.0.27     libsane-qcam.so.1.0.27        libsane-teco3.so.1
libsane-canon630u.so.1            libsane-epson2.so.1              libsane-hp.so.1              libsane-mustek_pp.so.1         libsane-ricoh.so.1            libsane-teco3.so.1.0.27
libsane-canon630u.so.1.0.27       libsane-epson2.so.1.0.27         libsane-hp.so.1.0.27         libsane-mustek_pp.so.1.0.27    libsane-ricoh.so.1.0.27       libsane-test.so.1
libsane-canon_dr.so.1             libsane-epsonds.so.1             libsane-hs2p.so.1            libsane-mustek.so.1            libsane-rts8891.so.1          libsane-test.so.1.0.27
libsane-canon_dr.so.1.0.27        libsane-epsonds.so.1.0.27        libsane-hs2p.so.1.0.27       libsane-mustek.so.1.0.27       libsane-rts8891.so.1.0.27     libsane-u12.so.1
libsane-canon_pp.so.1             libsane-epson.so.1               libsane-ibm.so.1             libsane-mustek_usb2.so.1       libsane-s9036.so.1            libsane-u12.so.1.0.27
libsane-canon_pp.so.1.0.27        libsane-epson.so.1.0.27          libsane-ibm.so.1.0.27        libsane-mustek_usb2.so.1.0.27  libsane-s9036.so.1.0.27       libsane-umax1220u.so.1
libsane-canon.so.1                libsane-fujitsu.so.1             libsane-kodakaio.so.1        libsane-mustek_usb.so.1        libsane-sceptre.so.1          libsane-umax1220u.so.1.0.27
libsane-canon.so.1.0.27           libsane-fujitsu.so.1.0.27        libsane-kodakaio.so.1.0.27   libsane-mustek_usb.so.1.0.27   libsane-sceptre.so.1.0.27     libsane-umax_pp.so.1
libsane-cardscan.so.1             libsane-genesys.so.1             libsane-kodak.so.1           libsane-nec.so.1               libsane-sharp.so.1            libsane-umax_pp.so.1.0.27
libsane-cardscan.so.1.0.27        libsane-genesys.so.1.0.27        libsane-kodak.so.1.0.27      libsane-nec.so.1.0.27          libsane-sharp.so.1.0.27       libsane-umax.so.1
libsane-coolscan2.so.1            libsane-gphoto2.so.1             libsane-kvs1025.so.1         libsane-net.so.1               libsane-sm3600.so.1           libsane-umax.so.1.0.27
libsane-coolscan2.so.1.0.27       libsane-gphoto2.so.1.0.27        libsane-kvs1025.so.1.0.27    libsane-net.so.1.0.27          libsane-sm3600.so.1.0.27      libsane-xerox_mfp.so.1
libsane-coolscan3.so.1            libsane-gt68xx.so.1              libsane-kvs20xx.so.1         libsane-niash.so.1             libsane-sm3840.so.1           libsane-xerox_mfp.so.1.0.27
libsane-coolscan3.so.1.0.27       libsane-gt68xx.so.1.0.27         libsane-kvs20xx.so.1.0.27    libsane-niash.so.1.0.27        libsane-sm3840.so.1.0.27

philip@Aspire-A715-71G:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sane$ cd ~
philip@Aspire-A715-71G:~$ sudo apt install libusb-0.1-4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libusb-0.1-4
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 17,1 kB of archives.
After this operation, 57,3 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Get:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 libusb-0.1-4 amd64 2:0.1.12-31 [17,1 kB]
Fetched 17,1 kB in 0s (37,2 kB/s)       
Selecting previously unselected package libusb-0.1-4:amd64.
(Reading database ... 191845 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libusb-0.1-4_2%3a0.1.12-31_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libusb-0.1-4:amd64 (2:0.1.12-31) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libusb-0.1-4:amd64 (2:0.1.12-31) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
philip@Aspire-A715-71G:~$ scanimage -L
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
philip@Aspire-A715-71G:~$ scanimage
scanimage: output is not a file, exiting
philip@Aspire-A715-71G:~$ sudo scanimage -L
device `smfp:usb;04e8;3469;ZF5RB8KJ6C00J6L' is a Samsung M2070 Series on USB Scanner
```

And now my scanner works with usb-connection to my computer !

Comment: Please add output of `which simple-scan`, `snap list | grep simple` and `apt-cache policy simple-scan` to the question.

Comment: Yeah, I think that also. Much to learn from that thread.

Comment: This usually means that duplicate question has good and reproducible answer. Such method is used to save time while giving solution.

Comment: Ok, I understand.   No, my problem is not solved.  I have to analyze that other tread to see if that helps my problem.

Comment: Now is my problem solved ! :)     Thanks for all your help.

Comment: Great, thanks for letting us know. Please don't add [solved] to the title. I have tried to give a title that will help people with similar problems find this question. Please leave this title unless you feel it does not describe your problem.

Comment: Why should I not add [Solved] in the title when the problem is solved ?

Comment: The titleshift is no problem for me, if it makes it easier to find this solution to the problem in the forum.